# Run bash script from .net program

Tags: .net, bash, vb.net

I try to send a script (just echo for the moment) form .net command

```vb
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c sh test.sh"
proc.StartInfo.FileName = (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\bash.exe")
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\"
proc.Start()
proc.WaitForExit()
Me.RichTextBox1.Text = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
```

When I launch with argument "-c ls -l" for example it works. I have in my richtextbox content of my working folder and I see test.sh. Terminal close itself.

But when I try to launch "-c sh test.sh", nothing append terminal open, and stay open with nothing inside.

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Why would you like to run `bash -c sh test.sh` ? Just running `bash -c test.sh` is enough

Comment: Adding to the comment by Aserre: You *can* do it, but in this case, you would not run `test.sh` as bash-program, but as sh-program, and in this case I wonder why your invoke _bash.exe_ at all. Please make up your mind first what language test.sh is written in (bash, or sh, or whatever).